# Docker Container fails to start after moving to pi (exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am developing a node application with a docker container and it runs fine on my windows machine (Device it was built on) but when I export it with docker save it stops working after I upload it to my Raspberry Pi 4. The Pi returns `exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error` on container start. My best guess is that it is a architecture problem.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64  node:16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

VOLUME /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci --omit=dev

COPY . .

ENV ENV1=
ENV ENV2=
ENV ENV3=

CMD [ "node", "index.cjs" ]
```

I have tried adding `--platform=linux/amd64` as shown in current file to no success.